# How to embed url in new Mail from Mac OS Lion

Tags: macos, mail.app

I don't know how this feature is called. Here on stack exchange you can take some text and mark it as a url. The url is embedded below. Example:
[Google](http://www.google.de/)

Is there an equivalent in Mac OS Lions Mail Client, too? It looks better if you don't see the cluttering url. I searched the menu, but I couldn't find what I am looking for. I hope you got me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

First write the text for the link - then right click on the text, and select "Link->Add Link" - enter the URL, and click "OK" - and you have what you want.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Highlight the text that you want to link and press command+K (⌘+K or +K).

Then enter the URL into the popup.

Answer (score 0):

- Select the words what you have make a link (like [Google](http://www.google.com))
- right-click on it = you will get a contextual menu
- selcet "Link" -> "Add link..."
- enter URL
- done